# Java setting timezone while converting date from Mountain to Eastern to GMT

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert mountain time to eastern time to GMT time. But when I am getting the final date in the date field "gmtDate",it's back to my local date in mountain time.

Here are my questions:

- I am expecting to see 2 hrs of difference from mountain time to eastern time. But seeing only an hor of difference. What is wrong here?
- Again there should a six hours of difference from eastern time to GMT time but it is 5 hours of difference showing here. What is wrong?
- Finally, I tried to save the date and time as GMT but looks like it's coming back to mountain time. What is wrong here?

Here is my final output:

```
DEBUG [main] (MyClass.java:100) - local  : 2014-07-14 10:11:04 MDT
DEBUG [main] (MyClass.java:108) - est    : 2014-07-14 11:11:04 EST
DEBUG [main] (MyClass.java:110) - =================================================
DEBUG [main] (MyClass.java:113) - gmt    : 2014-07-14 16:11:04 GMT
DEBUG [main] (MyClass.java:125) - gmt date : Mon Jul 14 10:11:04 MDT 2014
DEBUG [main] (MyClass.java:127) - =================================================
```

Here is my example code:

```
private Date testTimeZone(Date date, TimeZone sourceTimeZone, TimeZone targetTimeZone) {

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");

    Date localdate = null;
    try {
        localdate = df.parse("2014-07-14 09:11:04 MST");
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOG.debug("local  : " + df.format(localdate));

    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    LOG.debug("est : " + df.format(localdate));

    LOG.debug("=================================================");

    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    LOG.debug("gmt : " + df.format(localdate));

    Date gmtDate = null;
    try {
        gmtDate = df.parse(df.format(localdate));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOG.debug("gmt date : " + gmtDate);

    LOG.debug("=================================================");

    return gmtDate;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `"America/New_York"` for Eastern, `"America/Denver"` for Mountain, and `"UTC"` instead of GMT.  Keep in mind that the US is currently on daylight saving time, and specifying only `"EST"` doesn't take that into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ran your code and instead of getting mountain time, I got `gmt date : Mon Jul 14 12:11:04 EDT 2014`

This timezone corresponds to my timezone which lead me to the discovery that Date.toString() uses the local timezone to format the date. Per the Java date specification, a Date is:

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.

So the whole DateFormat code you are dealing doesn't actually change a value. It just matters how it is output. The underlying number of milliseconds will never actually change

Also, EST is for the winter, and EDT (Eastern Daylight Time) is used in the summer (Change this and your first two questions are resolved)

Comment: **Use joda time instead.That will help with time zone**

Answer (score 1):

Java `Date` represents a moment in time, and does not include an internal `TimeZone`. Instead, you use the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (such as you already have!) to perform the display formatting.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
try {
  Date date = df.parse("2014-07-14 09:11:04 MST");
  df.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "EST" ) );
  System.out.println(df.format(date));
  df.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT" ) );
  System.out.println(df.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs

```
2014-07-14 11:11:04 EST
2014-07-14 16:11:04 GMT
```

The reason you get `gmt date : Mon Jul 14 10:11:04 MDT 2014` is because the `TimeZone` associated with the `DateFormat` is changed to MDT when you parse `localdate` - which is `local  : 2014-07-14 10:11:04 MDT` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The default timezone is your local timezone, so you should have used:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
LOG.debug("gmt date : " + df.format(gmtDate));
```

You probably want to be using UCT (Universal Coordated Time) .. that is what you want to store and retrieve (if you use a database or other store.  GMT represents an actual timezone now, UCT is the "reference" time.

Comment: A date object doesn't have a timezone according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html